# How to remove the '%23' from URLs?

Tags: python, flask

In a flask app, I imported an ontology using owlready.

Every link contains %23 before any class name or instance. According to ASCII Encoding Reference, %23 is assigned to '#' character.

After looking in the .owl file, I can see that every class name or instance has # symbol just before the name.

I edited the .owl file and deleted any # symbol from class and instances names which is fixing the problem and it removes the %23 from the link but I am looking for a better way to get the %23 removed from the links. If I remove all the # symbols from the .owl I probably ruining the format of the ontology.

I am attaching a screenshot where you can see the %23 just before the last word in the link (Coccus)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One alternative for you would be to map links from your app (the one you attached) to more friendlier ones. But since that should happen dynamically the return on investment is minimal.

[Url encoding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) is normal and common, what are your concerns for having it? Are you afraid that people can’t visually parse the URL?

Comment: I would prefer to have the links as clean as possible and look good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).